# UI-Router: Is it possible to change a query parameter while the state is loading?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing

I am wondering if it is possible to change query parameter in the ui-router while a state is still being loaded.

I was thinking along the following lines but this does not work...

```
$stateProvider
.state('foo',{
  url:'/foo?bar',
  templateUrl:'app/foo.html', 
  controller: 'fooController as foo',
  resolve: {
    Resource: function($state) {
      return somepromise()
        .then(function(baz) {
          if (baz !== some condition) {
            $state.params.bar = 'newValue';
            return;
          }
      });
    }
  }
```

Any Suggestion? Thanks...

Comment: What if you do some 'redirect', instead of 

    $state.params.bar = 'newValue';
    $state.go('foo', { 'bar' : 'newValue} );

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish, actually change the url?

Comment: @charlietfl Here is what I am trying to accomplish. The user specifies some route `/foo` and how she wants to see the data `?bar`. If there is useful data returned while loading the route `/foo` but conducive to format `?bar`, I would still like to show the data but in a different format ie a different value for `bar`.

@Anfelipe I had tried you suggestion first up, but that seems to trigger a data re-fetch because it will reload state `foo`. That's what I am looking to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it inside the state declaration (I prefer this way)

```
.state('foo', {
    url: "/foo?bar", // not sure if this kind of url can be used
    template: "",
    controller: ['$state', function ($state, $stateParams) {
        if ($stateParams.bar == 'something') {
            $state.go('bar');
        }
    }]
})
```

Or you can redirect when the state is starting to change using event defined in ui-route

Normally I put these things in HomeController

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
    function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        //console.log("state change:", fromState.name, fromParams, toState.name, toParams);
        if (toState.name == 'foo' && toParams.bar == 'something') {
                $state.go('bar');
        }
    });
```

Do beware this might trigger an infinite loop if not handled correctly.

Comment: `$state.go('bar')` will take me to a `bar` state. I think you mean `$state.go('foo', { 'bar' : 'newValue'} );`. But the problem with this, as I mention in the comment above is that it triggers a reload of `foo`, which is basically an refetch from the server the server I want to avoid.

Comment: I think states with different params are treated as different states so it will trigger a reload. Perhaps what you need is switching child state instead of state param? You can also store your data in a service (which is a common practise) so reloading controller won't reload the data.

Comment: Yeah, that was my plan B. I am storing data in the service anyway, but then while loading, I need to check the service first and depending on situation there reload, which seems contrived. 
Being just able to change the param is so much simpler (also gives me better history)...